# and from where using mysql join

Tags: mysql

I need some help, I am kind of new to MySQL just started learning it well and understand JOIN very well

I am having a syntax error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;

It seems the error is around: `AND ( SELECT USERID FROM POSTS WHERE POST_USER = ''` at line 15

**My table :**

```
===========================================
TABLE USERS 
===========================================
USERID  |   NAME  |  COUNTRY |   STATE
===========================================
2       |   FRED  |  UK      |   LONDON 
3       |   MARK  |  USA     |   CALIFONIA 
4       |   JEFF  |  CA      |   TORONTO 
===========================================

========================================
TABLE POSTS
========================================
POSTID | USERID  | POST_TO  | POST
========================================
2      | 3       | USERID 1   | HEY 
3      | 1       | USERID 3   | SUP 
========================================
```

**My query :**

```
    SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE,
  P.POST
FROM USERS AS S
INNER JOIN POSTS AS P ON P.USERID = S.USERID AND P.USERID = 1 #THIS SHOULD BE DISPLAYING THE POST_TO NAMES, BUT SHOWING THE POST SENDER NAMES IN HIS ACCOUNT INSTEAD SHOWING RECEIVER NAMES
# ITS LIKE SELECT POST WHERE MY USERID = 1 / DISPLAY NAMES OF THESE PEOPLE I SENT POST TO ON COLUMN POST_TO

UNION

# THIS SECTION IS WORKING OK 
# OR THERE ANYTHING CAN BE DONE ITS OK TO BE CHANGED 
SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE,
  P.POST
FROM USERS AS S
INNER JOIN POSTS AS P ON P.USERID = S.USERID AND P.POST_USER = 'USERID 3'


I AM USER 3 - LOGGED IN. I SEE POST FROM USERID 1

I AM USER 1 - LOGGED IN. 
I MUST SEE I SENT POST TO USERID 3
```

Comment: 'understand JOIN very well' - you need to review joins, and a from with an and is just wrong.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: Can you explain what result do you want so we can help you build your query?

Comment: MySQL's FROM clause can only contain a `SELECT ...` or `(SELECT ...)` not  `(SELECT ...) AND (SELECT ...)` which is invalid SQL  see these demos https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8QDpB7cFYAZ8oMmBtFrHJ4/1 and https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8QDpB7cFYAZ8oMmBtFrHJ4/0

Comment: It looks like you need `Union`

Comment: @RaymondNijland we can always get two columns. one select considering empty value for the first, and second select considering empty value for the second one. But I am just throwing wild ideas, as the problem currently stands unclear.

Comment: What is the difference between column `userid` and `post_user`?

Comment: Based on the sample data, please add expected output to your question.

Comment: I tried to follow the first answer `SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      POST
    FROM
      POSTS
    WHERE
      USERID = '1'   #THIS WILL BRING POST (SUP) 
  )S
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      USERID
    FROM
      POSTS
    WHERE
      POST_USER = 'USERID 3'  #THIS WILL BRING USERID 3 DETAILS LIKE NAME
  )C ON S.USERID = C.USERID` but am getting `Unknown column 'S.USERID' in 'field list'` maybe table users not linked on the join statment

Comment: @MickaelLeger i wanted to select these people who sent me posts and the one i sent posts to

Comment: @FredBrown : you have no USERID = 1, is it normal?

Comment: @MickaelLeger yes its normal it was just a sample

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I will give you example using those data :

```
===========================================
TABLE USERS 
===========================================
USERID  | NAME  |  COUNTRY | STATE
===========================================
1       | PAUL  |  FR      | PARIS
2       | FRED  |  UK      | LONDON 
3       | MARK  |  USA     | CALIFONIA 
4       | JEFF  |  CA      | TORONTO 
===========================================

========================================
TABLE POSTS
========================================
POSTID | USERID  | POST_USER  | POST
========================================
2      | 3       | USERID 3   | HEY 
3      | 1       | USERID 1   | SUP 
========================================
```

To select all data using with column from both table, you can do :

```
SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE,
  P.POST
FROM USERS AS S
LEFT JOIN POSTS AS P ON P.USERID = S.USERID
```

With this query you will get this :

```
USERID | NAME | COUNTRY | STATE      | POST
1      | PAUL | FR      | PARIS      | SUP
2      | FRED | UK      | LONDON     | NULL  // POST is NULL because no USERID = 2 in POSTS table
3      | MARK | USA     | CALIFORNIA | HEY  
4      | JEFF | CA      | TORONTO    | NULL  // POST is NULL because no USERID = 4 in POSTS table
```

Now if you want to get only result with a `POST` value, you can do this :

```
SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE,
  P.POST
FROM USERS AS S
INNER JOIN POSTS AS P ON P.USERID = S.USERID
```

Result will be :

```
USERID | NAME | COUNTRY | STATE      | POST
1      | PAUL | FR      | PARIS      | SUP
3      | MARK | USA     | CALIFORNIA | HEY
```

Here you have only row where `POST` is not NULL

Now if you want to return value with a condition on one of the value of table USER, you can do :

```
SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE,
  P.POST
FROM USERS AS S
LEFT JOIN POSTS AS P ON P.USERID = S.USERID
WHERE USERID = 1
```

Result will be :

```
USERID | NAME | COUNTRY | STATE      | POST
1      | PAUL | FR      | PARIS      | SUP
```

If you want a condition on the `POSTS` table, you can use the `INNER JOIN` as before with a new condition :

```
SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE,
  P.POST
FROM USERS AS S
INNER JOIN POSTS AS P ON P.USERID = S.USERID AND P.POST_USER = 'USERID 3'
```

Result will be :

```
USERID | NAME | COUNTRY | STATE      | POST
3      | MARK | USA     | CALIFORNIA | HEY
```

Now if you want to return multiple row with different condition, you can use `UNION` (warning : each select must return the same column) :

```
SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE,
  P.POST
FROM USERS AS S
INNER JOIN POSTS AS P ON P.USERID = S.USERID AND P.USERID = 1

UNION

SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE,
  P.POST
FROM USERS AS S
INNER JOIN POSTS AS P ON P.USERID = S.USERID AND P.POST_USER = 'USERID 3'
```

Result will be :

```
USERID | NAME | COUNTRY | STATE      | POST
1      | PAUL | FR      | PARIS      | SUP  // Result of first SELECT with P.USERID = 1
3      | MARK | USA     | CALIFORNIA | HEY  // Result of second SELECT with P.POST_USER = 'USERID 3'
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks alot it worked and i also learnt and got idea how union works. i only have 1 error in your last union example. i dont know if its ok to post here or open other post. but really thanks alot

Comment: What is the error just to know if I can correct it?

Comment: `SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE,
  P.POST
FROM USERS AS S
INNER JOIN POSTS AS P ON P.USERID = S.USERID AND P.USERID = 1 #THIS SHOULD BE DISPLAYING THE POST_TO NAMES, BUT SHOWING THE POST SENDER NAMES IN HIS ACCOUNT INSTEAD SHOWING RECEIVER NAMES

UNION

SELECT
  S.USERID,
  S.NAME,
  S.COUNTRY,
  S.STATE,
  P.POST
FROM USERS AS S
INNER JOIN POSTS AS P ON P.USERID = S.USERID AND P.POST_USER = 'USERID 3'


I AM USER 3 - LOGGED IN. I SEE POST FROM USERID 1

I AM USER 1 - LOGGED IN. 
I MUST SEE I SENT POST TO USERID 3 
 `

Comment: Ok so this is not an error, the query just don't show you what you want :) You should show us (not just explain) what is the desired output you want so I can help you build the query to get it

Comment: yes its not error. but thats want i wanted. i dont know how it can be done. am not really at that level of doing that. am just starting things

Comment: Just edit your question with your sample data and give an example of how the query is supposed to be